# How do i stop the perfectionism with textbooks?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, education

I have this problem that whenever i want to dip my toes into a new area of math that I'm either completely new to or have so little knowledge in it, I always go and google "Best books to learn [SUBJECT]" or I go and take a look at the recommendations in [r/math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/)

And honestly it's driving me crazy, i spend days making a collection of the "Best" books for that subject and most times, i end up using non and ready what my Uni prof. would say for the given course.

for example, It's been three days that I've been looking for a "Perfect" discrete mathematics books and after 5 days, I have downloaded about 9 pdfs and read non while i could've read a chapter completely.

How do i stop this? how do i stop looking for the *Perfect* textbook? If i don't do this, i always feel like there's a better textbook out there that i could've read and gained more knowledge while i know that's just a wrong feeling.

I would really really appreciate if you could give me any, absolutely any possible advice to stop this perfectionism

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Why not just ask your professor(s) and/or academic advisor(s) directly for recommendations? ... In any case, this isn't really a question about Mathematics, so don't be surprised if it gets closed.

Comment: If nothing else, remind yourself that any ranking of that sort is going to be extremely subjective.  The books I like might not suit you so well, and conversely.  At most, I'd say that seeing some book on a number of recommended lists at least suggests that it's pretty good and that it has a wide appeal. And besides, if you get a "bad"  one, you'll see its flaws and seeking out repairs will lead you to sources you end up preferring.

Comment: thanks. because the professors in my university aren't really up-to-date with textbook references and etc. in these 3 semesters that i've been stuyding, non of the textbooks have been younger that 20 years old. @Blue

Comment: A new book might not necessarily be better. As long as it's not about cutting edge research, older books often contain the same facts as new books. And the fact that some of those are still around shows that they remain popular and useful. Some books are such good and complete discussions of certain areas that there is really no reason to use another book, and not clear how a "new" book could be any better.

Comment: Imo this post is peripherally, but still, about Maths - the recommendations would be different for other subjects.

Comment: There are definitely books that are just bad, and then there are books that are good, and everywhere in-between. And for the books that are good, you still have to consider what suits your personal style. For instance, I loved Hatcher's book on algebraic topology (creatively named "Algebraic Topology") precisely for the same reason that many others I know hate it: it has less focus on rigor and formalisms, and more focus on concrete examples and intuitive explanations.

Comment: *non of the textbooks have been younger that 20 years old* --- I think 20 years is too restrictive to worry about. Notation and terminology in math has hardly changed since the 1960s (at least) and the core topics at the undergraduate level have also hardly changed since the 1960s. Also, if you talk to people who taught in the 1960s and 1970s, you'll often find them saying that textbooks that would have been appropriate then are too difficult for students now (e.g. 2nd to last paragraph of [this review](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/differential-geometry-of-curves-and-surfaces-1)).

Comment: Few mathematicians I think find the textbooks they read perfect. That's why many of them sooner or later write their own.

Comment: Aw, my favorite math textbooks are nearly all 100-2000 years old.

Answer (score 1):

This is more common than you might think. There are a lot of books on every topic, and each one has a different focus, style, and level of technicality. Personally, I don't think there *is* a perfect book for you (or anybody else). My personal strategy would be something like this:

1. Decide on the level of technicality (with/without proofs, is it a graduate or undergraduate text?) and the sub-topics you are interested in.
2. Look for a book that fulfills the criteria you have set yourself in 1.
3. Accept that it might not be perfect, and go with it.
4. This book will, if you study the topic using this book, eventually become one of your preferred sources (unless it is really bad ;) ). It's like most people do not question the syllabus/style/notation/... of a lecture. Rather the lecture becomes the standard against which they compare other sources on that topic.